# Dynamically loading coupled HTML/CSS files into the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, requirejs

For my project, I am using require.js as a dependency manager Each component loads it's own html via the requirejs text plugin and appends itself into the right place in the DOM.

One of the things that ends up happening is that there are numerous style tags inline with the html. For instance:

```
<div id="menuComponent">
     .....
</div>

<style>
     #menuComponent {
          .... 
     }
     ....
<style>
```

This results in the css is now no longer being part of an external stylesheet, and inline with each corresponding component in the html when the script compiles.

1. Is this considered bad practice to have many `<style>` tags inline with the code?
2. If so, how should I go about moving the stylesheets into a centralized location?

Comment: Non-scoped `style` elements are only allowed in `head`.

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/guybedford/require-css

Comment: Thanks @DavidAlsbright! That actually might be exactly what I want to integrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including `<style>` within `body` is valid HTML5 only if the `scoped` attribute is present.

*From the HTML5 spec:*

The scoped attribute is a boolean attribute. If set, it indicates that the styles are intended just for the subtree rooted at the style element’s parent element, as opposed to the whole Document.

---

In your case, I would suggest taking a look at require-css: https://github.com/guybedford/require-css

It will allow you to include CSS in a separate file if needed.

*From the require-css docs:*

To output the CSS to a separate file, use the configuration:

```
{
  separateCSS: true,
  modules: [
  {
    name: 'mymodule'
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Comment: https://github.com/martinsb/require-css